# Regular Expression for Phrases (not just words)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

Is it possible to use a regular expression to match one of multiple strings separated by spaces? I am trying to match email sign-offs such as:

```
array.match(/Thanks|(Thank You)/);
```

But the second match does not seem to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: please edit your question to include the sample input you're testing against

Comment: ... and what you mean by "does not seem to be working"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put both phrases in the same capture group?

`array.match(/(Thanks|Thank You)/);`

Example [here](http://regexr.com/3e73g)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apparently both ways  array.match(/(Thanks|Thank You)/); and array.match(/Thanks|(Thank You)/); work the same. It was some other part of my code that was causing this not to match.